# Matching hashes in a file

Tags: python, regex, hash

I have a file that contains hashes, what I need to do is match all the certain hashes with a regular expression, if there is a simpler way please elaborate, however this file contains multiple different types of hashes:

*Please note that the hash type is only in this file for testing purposes, hash types will not be in the file*

```
SHA1 => a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
SHA1 => c8cc3f3b4b33523b8c180da8562a5dc42a00677c
SHA1 => abf6021ef8e11106b894bea04c03e9d8a8de17a6
SHA224 => 90a3ed9e32b2aaf4c61c410eb925426119e1a9dc53d4286ade99a809
SHA224 => 40e223e699912131a99ee76c5e065827373c67bdfaf99d944fe8dfc8
SHA224 => 2acb3a17dd92e2bf54b345b3711e8ead183e01794aafced5ed4ad23e
SHA => f8d3b312442a67706057aeb45b983221afb4f035
SHA => 0c37a678e8eef041b82b3025e64fc01a670bb0f0
SHA => 1f77da8f9d10720e6bbd35b0b998bd7f0bb79381
SHA384 => 768412320f7b0aa5812fce428dc4706b3cae50e02a64caa16a782249bfe8efc4b7ef1ccb126255d196047dfedf17a0a9
SHA384 => 67d36f4834cb7e79788381f849c21a63b968732bf0f3fac24bf4b24423b797fd12269e2cd7fa428bdc86a48ada5e3577
SHA384 => b66651b7190abc1abdb8c7829207a06335045c353b748462a193042be584603a85587b95806f3fef1da8b1da983d5fb1
ecdsa-with-SHA1 => a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
ecdsa-with-SHA1 => c8cc3f3b4b33523b8c180da8562a5dc42a00677c
ecdsa-with-SHA1 => abf6021ef8e11106b894bea04c03e9d8a8de17a6
SHA256 => 9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08
SHA256 => 34ad260fd7ffae7f4b5c716da1d9d422f95775a5f6f5b910201adfa303ef26a8
SHA256 => 8f2cfb70a71a9f40f95322d176998edce14122a16fa208a8b1cc993d36df3f1d
SHA512 => ee26b0dd4af7e749aa1a8ee3c10ae9923f618980772e473f8819a5d4940e0db27ac185f8a0e1d5f84f88bc887fd67b143732c304cc
5fa9ad8e6f57f50028a8ff
SHA512 => d0351496ef238247ccba08518f10678a6211080a98a6128fa49bd225a2bbec360e3e1b93759f68c14ae3b95096fd81682c1f4a1453
e0057af4a55a910d3066b2
SHA512 => b4cc5ce80cc15910c6e87b15adf1df5485f3165bb02cd5e2d95d3174e137de1d1b6eb0f67ace107f16a234682edd72a6896645969b
19691f38a12199dfc5007e
md4 => db346d691d7acc4dc2625db19f9e3f52
md4 => 4506d07a12e2d2b8f26485a455d6c69f
md4 => 369ee30df7b4b261d5dcd5b607ffca17
md5 => 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
md5 => cb466b639885e93973c0a272c339ff9a
md5 => ae696df69ec720fbb46d52ebbc262fc8
sha1 => a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
sha1 => c8cc3f3b4b33523b8c180da8562a5dc42a00677c
sha1 => abf6021ef8e11106b894bea04c03e9d8a8de17a6
dsaWithSHA => a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
dsaWithSHA => c8cc3f3b4b33523b8c180da8562a5dc42a00677c
dsaWithSHA => abf6021ef8e11106b894bea04c03e9d8a8de17a6
DSA-SHA => a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
DSA-SHA => c8cc3f3b4b33523b8c180da8562a5dc42a00677c
DSA-SHA => abf6021ef8e11106b894bea04c03e9d8a8de17a6
sha224 => 90a3ed9e32b2aaf4c61c410eb925426119e1a9dc53d4286ade99a809
sha224 => 40e223e699912131a99ee76c5e065827373c67bdfaf99d944fe8dfc8
sha224 => 2acb3a17dd92e2bf54b345b3711e8ead183e01794aafced5ed4ad23e
dsaEncryption => a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
dsaEncryption => c8cc3f3b4b33523b8c180da8562a5dc42a00677c
dsaEncryption => abf6021ef8e11106b894bea04c03e9d8a8de17a6
DSA => a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
DSA => c8cc3f3b4b33523b8c180da8562a5dc42a00677c
DSA => abf6021ef8e11106b894bea04c03e9d8a8de17a6
ripemd160 => 5e52fee47e6b070565f74372468cdc699de89107
ripemd160 => b36b88d174a4d7cd16150f0071f150e74939bdcb
ripemd160 => 3d8e0e6cdf562d919887da3af417aa2ecdfa3031
sha => f8d3b312442a67706057aeb45b983221afb4f035
sha => 0c37a678e8eef041b82b3025e64fc01a670bb0f0
sha => 1f77da8f9d10720e6bbd35b0b998bd7f0bb79381
MD5 => 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
MD5 => cb466b639885e93973c0a272c339ff9a
MD5 => ae696df69ec720fbb46d52ebbc262fc8
MD4 => db346d691d7acc4dc2625db19f9e3f52
MD4 => 4506d07a12e2d2b8f26485a455d6c69f
MD4 => 369ee30df7b4b261d5dcd5b607ffca17
sha384 => 768412320f7b0aa5812fce428dc4706b3cae50e02a64caa16a782249bfe8efc4b7ef1ccb126255d196047dfedf17a0a9
sha384 => 67d36f4834cb7e79788381f849c21a63b968732bf0f3fac24bf4b24423b797fd12269e2cd7fa428bdc86a48ada5e3577
sha384 => b66651b7190abc1abdb8c7829207a06335045c353b748462a193042be584603a85587b95806f3fef1da8b1da983d5fb1
sha256 => 9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08
sha256 => 34ad260fd7ffae7f4b5c716da1d9d422f95775a5f6f5b910201adfa303ef26a8
sha256 => 8f2cfb70a71a9f40f95322d176998edce14122a16fa208a8b1cc993d36df3f1d
sha512 => ee26b0dd4af7e749aa1a8ee3c10ae9923f618980772e473f8819a5d4940e0db27ac185f8a0e1d5f84f88bc887fd67b143732c304cc
5fa9ad8e6f57f50028a8ff
sha512 => d0351496ef238247ccba08518f10678a6211080a98a6128fa49bd225a2bbec360e3e1b93759f68c14ae3b95096fd81682c1f4a1453
e0057af4a55a910d3066b2
sha512 => b4cc5ce80cc15910c6e87b15adf1df5485f3165bb02cd5e2d95d3174e137de1d1b6eb0f67ace107f16a234682edd72a6896645969b
19691f38a12199dfc5007e
RIPEMD160 => 5e52fee47e6b070565f74372468cdc699de89107
RIPEMD160 => b36b88d174a4d7cd16150f0071f150e74939bdcb
RIPEMD160 => 3d8e0e6cdf562d919887da3af417aa2ecdfa3031
whirlpool => b913d5bbb8e461c2c5961cbe0edcdadfd29f068225ceb37da6defcf89849368f8c6c2eb6a4c4ac75775d032a0ecfdfe85505730
62b653fe92fc7b8fb3b7be8d6
whirlpool => 838b401be3e04657e0559bc338ec1ac71cd810f35dadd9183152f9ceec089458a487ba11d871c1f1bc313a15b2e1f5cefd59a75
1724b0e0562c8bb616bfb6ee8
whirlpool => 6755e2341ff4cf4b50c6287f1809e217bb9b37d2eeeecd01cb720644c072cb51528377c1ab0de5462496efac14221b6c236bb30
96d386e186c59ab102c826ec3
```

I've come up with this regex for MD5: `([a-fA-F\d]{32,40})` this works, but it also matches almost half of the SHA hashes along with it, for example:

```
ae696df69ec720fbb46d52ebbc262fc8 #<= match
369ee30df7b4b261d5dcd5b607ffca17 #<= match
d0351496ef238247ccba08518f10678a <= match continue hash => 6211080a98a6128fa49bd225a2bbec360e3e1b93759f68c14ae3b95096fd81682c1f4a1453
e0057af4a55a910d3066b2
```

Is there a way I can match *only* MD hashes (`md4`, `md5`), along with *only* SHA hashes (`sha512`, `sha384`, `sha1`, etc..)?

Comment: So, you want all `MD` and `SHA` hash values?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque Yes

Comment: Is the hash type actually in the file or is that just for us?

Comment: For testing the type is in the file

Comment: @chris85 elaborate?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://regex101.com/r/ngsts4/1

Comment: @chris85 I think that will work for the MD hashes

Comment: and that is wrong? It works for the examples you cited.

Comment: @chris85 For me it doesn't, I removed the hash type from the hash string and it won't match any of them

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/tm6otz/1

Comment: Use the flags/modifiers I used. https://regex101.com/r/tm6otz/2

Comment: @chris85 Aww, yeah that works for some of the sha, and the md5 and md4, but there's sha512, sha1, sha384. etc that I still need to match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could rely on the `OR` sign in regex which is `|` to catch what you need. This will work only if the hashes have specific length. Based on @chris85 comment, we could further add `sha512` and `sha384` using `|` by specifying that for example sha512 has only `{52,60}` characters and sha384 has `{92,100}` characters, and so on. It will be something like this:

```
^(?:[a-fA-F\d]{32,40})$|^(?:[a-fA-F\d]{52,60})$|^(?:[a-fA-F\d]{92,100})$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/z5SoCS/1

You could further enhance your regex by using groups, and specifying a name for each hash. For example, you could do something like:

```
^(?<sha384>[a-fA-F\d]{92,100})$
```

Comment: All the data is hex to the regex is usless, the only hint is the length and a regex is not needed for that. Distinguish between MD4 and MD5 for one example, it is not possible.

Comment: @zaph I think regex can be useful in catching the hash string. It is true that it will not catch the difference between MD4 and MD5, but it will help find the pattern of the hash string itself, and distinguish it from other regular strings that contains a sentence or something like that. Regex helps identify that this string does not have any spaces, and only uses characters from A to F and numbers, and does not has special characters and so on. If you put this regex in a document that has lots of regular text and one hash, it is highly unlikely that it will catch anything other than the hash.

Comment: The point is that the regex gains nothing over just using the length. There are no spaces or non-hex characters in the file that will be used, see the question. There is no pattern in a cryptographic hash, each bit is essentially individual. A hash can not be distinguished from random bits, this is the property of a cryptographic hash.

Comment: @Ibrahim Well first, you got it all wrong, nobody is trying to distinguish between MD4 and MD5, I'm trying to pull all the `MD` (meaning MD4 and MD5) out of a text file containing hashes. So you're response does not answer my question at all. This one does

Comment: @papasmurf I'm glad my answer helped you. Is your comment directed to me or zaph?

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell the hash algorithm that created a hash by examining the output.

All the hashes in the question are expressed in hexadecimal so it is not possible to tell the hash that created then by their contents.

The best that can be done is to look at the length but there will be several hashes that could create a particular length.

If you need to know the hash you will need to code the hashed in some manner such as a prefix.